# Parallax Navigating Between Sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

[Click here to see live demo.](http://inmyownview.com/pagan/)

I want to navigate between the sections with a nice animation. Each "page" in the parallax design is divided into `<section>`'s. Parts of my code is shown below.

```
<div id="sliding">
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5
        </div>
    <section data-type="background" data-speed="20" style="background: url('http://media.vogue.com/files/2012/08/15/img-4vogue120erdemjpg_133133774497.jpg') 50% 0 repeat fixed; min-h-margin: 0 auto; height: 1000px;">
        bla bla
    </section>
    <section data-type="background" data-speed="10" style="background: url('http://media.vogue.com/files/2013/01/15/storm-troupers-02_191346273703.jpg') 50% 0 repeat fixed; min-h-margin: 0 auto; height: 1000px;">
        bla bla bla
    </section>
```

Comment: -1: So what's the question? What have you tried?

Comment: How can I do it? That's my question. I could use for example <a href="#firstpage"> but the "pages" are all divided into sections. @TiesonT

Answer (score 0):

Give the sections unique ID's, turn your pagination dots into hyperlinks with a target that matches those IDs, and use localScroll to give you a nice animation.

Read more and download:
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html

You'd do something like this in your html:

```
<!-- snip -->

<head>
    <!-- this loads the scripts in the correct order -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollTo.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/localScroll.min.js">
</head>

<!-- snip -->

<div id="sliding">
    <a href="#section1">1</a>
    <a href="#section2">2</a>
    <a href="#section3">3</a>
    <a href="#section4">4</a>
    <a href="#section5">5</a>
</div>
<section id="section1" ... etc.
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
$('a').localScroll();
```

That's it! You'll see a smooth scroll animation when you click on one of the section links (without localScroll, it will just jump directly to that section).

Comment: It's not working. Look at the test http://inmyownview.com/pagan/test.php @jdiaz5513

Comment: It's a jQuery plugin, so jQuery needs to be loaded first. Move your script tags around. The file that you included (scroll.js) is just the scrollTo plugin, you also need to include localScroll.js (localScroll depends on scrollTo). Updated answer to illustrate how to load the dependencies in the correct order.